# How can I create a font that uses line breaks in Skyrim?

Tags: fonts

I [created a mod](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/102917) for Skyrim that changes the font to Calibri. Unfortunately I'm running in to an issue with the [Ordinator mod](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/1137) where the perk descriptions get cut off because there is no line break like there is in the vanilla font (see screenshots).

I've checked online extensively, made numerous changes to the font in FontForge, and even compared my mod versus other font mods and I'm not seeing a connection as to why theirs works and mine does not.

Vanilla:
[image]

Modded:
[image]